# How to expose redirection between pods outside k8s cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I'm to setup druid cluster with k8s and I'm seeking for help about how to expose redirection between pods outside k8s cluster.
Say I have two ClusterIP services to expose pods outside k8s.

- service(10.0.0.1:8080) -> pod(hostname: coordinator)
- service1(10.0.0.2:8080) -> pod1(hostname: coordinator1)
- pod and pod1 are druid coordinator groups communicating via Zookepper. Since pod1 is the leader, every request to pod1 will be redirect to pod.
- In this setup, I'm good with service but facing redirection issues while visiting service.

  - When I visit service1(10.0.0.2:8080) via browser, I'll be redirect to pod via its hostname, i.e. coordinator:8081.
  - However, coordinator is unkown outside k8s cluster and thus unreachable.

Could you please give me some suggestion on how to deal with this situation? Any tips is appreciate.

---

Here is the return after running `wget -S -O - 10.0.0.1:8081`

`--2017-07-21 16:36:18--  http://10.0.0.1:8081/
Connecting to 10.0.0.1:8081... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 
  HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
  Date: Fri, 21 Jul 2017 08:36:25 GMT
  Location: http://coordinator:8081/
  Content-Length: 0
  Server: Jetty(9.3.16.v20170120)
Location: http://coordinator:8081/ [following]
--2017-07-21 16:36:18--  http://coordinator:8081/
Resolving coordinator (coordinator)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'coordinator'`

Comment: Can you run `wget -S -O - http://10.0.0.1:8080` and post all output please? (Assuming this is a http service)

Comment: Hi, Lenart. Thank you for your quick reply. I updated the results after runing wget command in my question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to my mind (although a bit overenginered) is to make sure you always hit only the leader.

If you can create a readiness check against your pods that returns ok if it is the leader and link them to a common service, that service will always direct to the active leader.

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion. If I ended up with no k8s built-in function to support it, i'll definitely try to implement this kind of proxy service. Thank you and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with kubernetes. The application server (Jetty) issues the redirect (to 'coordinator'; not 'coordinator1/2' which is another problem), not kube-proxy.

Probably the simplest solution is to setup an nginx inside your cluster to do reverse proxy to handle that redirect.

(You also don't need 2 services like you have now either)

Comment: Hi Lenart, I'm sorry that I typed something wrong with my real setup. In my setup, I have `coordinator` and `coordinator1`. The issue is when I visit coordinator1, the Jetty server issues redirect to coordinator(the leader).. Thank you for your suggestion and I'll look into how to implement reverse proxy. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**nginx + confd**

I had exactly the same problem and found the best solution in installing an nginx reverse proxy, forwarding all traffic to the current leader. The nginx config gets updated by [confd](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/confd), which is watching zookeeper for changes at the overlord/coordinator discovery keys.

To set things up, I found [this article](http://thecookiezen.com/blog/2016/12/12/data-synchronization-in-distributed-environment-part-1/) quite helpful.